# get contacts Birthday in iphone

Tags: iphone

I got the code from stackoverflow  of getting contacts birthday in label in iphone but it is printing in console 2013-01-09 13:31:15.913 addressBook[1478:c07] 1604-09-29 12:00:00 +0000
so how can only print birthdate.plz help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use NSDateFormatter like this

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MMM dd, yyyy"];
NSString *dte=[dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];

[dateFormatter release];
NSLog(@"Birthdate : %@",dte);
```